# getting access token from http context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 in authenticating my applications and web apis. 
My client application (vuejs) implements a implicit grant type.

In my WEB API, I have this setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
             .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => {
                 options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:BaseUrls:Identity").Value;
                 options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                 options.SaveToken = true;
                 options.ApiName = "myapi";
             });
```

Within my controller, I'm using:

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

to get my token. It was working until last week when I upgraded to dotnet core 2.1.

After upgrading, it returns null.

Old version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.7" />
```

New Version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.1" />
```

Comment: What was the .NET Core version before the update?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: As an aside, per Microsoft guidance you should be [Migrating from Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage#migrate).

Comment: OK, I'll look into upgrading to that

Answer (score 1):

you can add the following to your `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` section

`options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents() {
   OnTokenValidated = async context => {
      var accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
      if (accessToken != null) {
         ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
         if (identity != null) {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken.RawData));
         }
      }
  }
}`

Then you can access the token by using `Request.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("access_token").Value`

Comment: I'm suffering the same problem, but this feels like a hack. Why isn't HttpContext.GetTokenAsync() working?